# не работают стили при input[type=radio]:checked

Tags: html, css

```css
label{
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}

label::after{
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

input[type=radio]:checked label::after{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label for="test">
  <input type="radio" id="test">
</label>
```

Comment: а они и не должны работать) вы ищете label внутри тега input... если вам нужно достучаться к родителю, то такое через css сделать нельзя) (scss или js в помощь)

Comment: `input[type=checkbox]` и `<input type="radio"` - ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, но CSS не умеет смотреть "назад", точнее обращаться к родительскому элементу..
А ваш `label` как раз является родителем `input`.

По этому придётся выкручиваться как-то так:

```css
label{
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}

label::after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label::after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test">
<label for="test"></label>
```

---

А ещё у вас ошибка, в HTML вы пишите `<input type="radio">`, а в CSS обращаетесь к `checkbox`.